# Solve the separable differential equation: 2*sqrt(xy)*(dy/dx)=1

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the separable differential equation:

$2\sqrt{xy} {dy \over dx} = 1 $

$ x,y>0 $

I understand the process. But I keep getting $ C={4y^({2\over 3})\over 3}-2\sqrt{x} $ as my answer, when the book says the answer is $C={2y^({2\over 3})\over 3}-\sqrt{x}$. I just don't understand how/where the 2 is being factored out.

Comment: Rewrite the equation as $2\sqrt{y}dy=\dfrac{dx}{\sqrt{x}}$.

Comment: @user364321: **Hint:** You have $\displaystyle 2 \int \sqrt{y}~ dy = \int \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x}}~dx$.

Comment: I integrated both sides but I keep getting $ C={4y^({2\over 3})\over 3}-2\sqrt{x}  $ as my answer. But the book says the answer is $ C={2y^({2\over 3})\over 3}-\sqrt{x}   $. I just don't understand how/where the 2 is being factored out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rearrange your equation to separate the variables:

$$
\begin{split}
2\sqrt{xy} {dy \over dx} &= 1  \\
2\sqrt{y}dy&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}dx 
\end{split}
$$

Now integrate both side:

$$
\begin{split}
\int{2\sqrt{y}dy}&= \int{\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}dx}  \\
2\frac{2}{3}y^{\frac{3}{2}} &= 2\sqrt{x} + C    \\
y &= \bigg(\frac{3}{2}(\sqrt{x} + C_1)\bigg)^{\frac{2}{3}}
\end{split}
$$

Comment: I keep getting $ C={4y^({2\over 3})\over 3}-2\sqrt{x}  $ as my answer. But the book says the answer is $ C={2y^({2\over 3})\over 3}-\sqrt{x}   $. I just don't understand how/where the 2 is being factored out.

Comment: $C$ is just a constant so it doesn't matter if you factor out the 2. Look at the last two lines in my solution; note how I just replace $\frac{C}{2}$ with a new constant $C_1$.

Comment: Oh, ok. I understand now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just separate

$$2y^{1\over 2}dy=x^{-1\over 2}dx$$

Next remember that the antiderivative of $x^\alpha$

$$\left({x^{\alpha+1}\over \alpha+1}\right)'=x^\alpha$$

So we can write

$${4\over 3}y^{3\over 2}+C=2x^{1\over 2}$$

And this can be rearranged as

$$y=\left({3\over 2}\sqrt{x}+C\right)^{2\over 3}$$